# How I can replace all values in table dynamically in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My current table is like 
[image]

where `UserId` has 14 columns from `ys_ar_item1` to `ys_ar_item14` for multiple clients. I have to change or update the values in this table such that 0 should be replaced by 1, 1 should be replaced by 2, 2 should be replaced by 3 up to 6 should be replaced by 7, and `nil` should be replaced by 0.

For example: `ys_ar_item1` should be 31245 instead of 20134.

Here is Sample table for 3 columns, it will be for all columns that is 14.

[image]

Note - It would be fine to create a new table with `UserId` and 14 columns.

Comment: @Sami - I have to replace all the values in all columns of table .

Comment: Are `Ys_Ar_Item1` ... datatype is varchar or int?

Comment: datatype is  VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Can you show real SQL code for the tables, or at least screenshots of SQL Server, and not mockups made in Excel? And is that really your database structure? It looks horribly denormalised, making this far more difficult than it should be.

Comment: @underscore_d It can't be done with nasted `REPLACE()` anyway, it will become '777777'

Comment: _"Note - fine to create new table with id and 14 columns"_ This would still be a subpar design unless there's a concrete rationale for it. You should have a table mapping `UserID`s to arbitrary numbers of `ys_ar_item`s or whatever those are.

Comment: You need to show your own efforts, Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47886685/edit) and add all relevant code that you already wrote into it. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: @PeterB - will do

Comment: @KulOmkar With this design and what you provide, I can only think of one way to solve this issue by using `CAST(REPLICATE('1', LEN(Col)) as INT) + Col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already mentioned, this is a bad database design.
But you can try the following function to get the desired result:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplaceNumbers
(
    @str varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @result varchar(max)
DECLARE @cnt int=1
WHILE @cnt <= LEN(@str)
    BEGIN
        SET @result = CONCAT(@result,
                            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@str,@cnt,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6')
                            THEN CAST(PARSE(SUBSTRING(@str,@cnt,1) AS int)+1 AS varchar)
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(@str,@cnt,1) END)

        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    END;

RETURN REPLACE(@result, 'nil', '0')
END
```

Use it like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET ys_ar_item1=dbo.ReplaceNumbers(ys_ar_item1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really bad design and you store numbers as strings which makes things hard, but I can think just of using those functions `IIF()`, `TRY_CAST()` and `REPLICATE()`:

```
CREATE TABLE Sample (
    UserID INT,
    Ys_Ar_Item1 VARCHAR(10),
    Ys_Ar_Item2 VARCHAR(10),
    Ys_Ar_Item3 VARCHAR(10)
    -- Other columns
    );

INSERT INTO Sample VALUES
(1, '20134', 'nil NULL', '02341');

SELECT UserID,
       IIF(TRY_CAST(Ys_Ar_Item1 AS INT) IS NULL, '0', CAST( REPLICATE('1', LEN(Ys_Ar_Item1) ) AS INT) + CAST(Ys_Ar_Item1 AS INT)) AS Ys_Ar_Item1,
       IIF(TRY_CAST(Ys_Ar_Item2 AS INT) IS NULL, '0', CAST( REPLICATE('1', LEN(Ys_Ar_Item2) ) AS INT) + CAST(Ys_Ar_Item2 AS INT)) AS Ys_Ar_Item2,
       IIF(TRY_CAST(Ys_Ar_Item3 AS INT) IS NULL, '0', CAST( REPLICATE('1', LEN(Ys_Ar_Item3) ) AS INT) + CAST(Ys_Ar_Item3 AS INT)) AS Ys_Ar_Item3
FROM Sample;
```

Note:

In the sample data you include in your question as an image, there is no number >6, this solution will fail if you have such numbers.